# Webscraping with beautifulsoup 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn beautifulsoup to **scrape** the text from NYT politics articles, currently with the code I have right now, it does manage to scrape through two paragraphs, but then after that, it spits out AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'. I've looked this error up and some threads claim that the error originates from using legacy functions from beautifulsoup3. But that doesn't seem to be the problem here, any ideas?

Code:

```
import requests
from urllib import request, response, error, parse
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup




url = "https://www.nytimes.com/2020/02/10/us/politics/trump-manchin-impeachment.html"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


title = soup.title
titleText = title.get_text()

body = soup.find('article', class_='css-1vxca1d')

section = soup.find('section', class_="css-1r7ky0e")
for elem in section:
    div1 = elem.findAll('div')
    for x in div1:
        div2 = elem.findAll('div')
        for i in div2:
            text = i.find('p').get_text()
            print (text)
            print("----------")
```

output:

```
WASHINGTON — Senator Joe Manchin III votes with President Trump more than any other Democrat in the Senate. But his vote last week to convict Mr. Trump of impeachable offenses has eclipsed all of that, earning him the rage of a president who coveted a bipartisan acquittal.
----------
“Munchkin means that you’re small, right?” he said. “I’m bigger than him — of course he has me by weight, now, he has more volume than I have by about 30 or 40 pounds. I’m far from being weak and pathetic, and I’m far from being a munchkin, and I still want him to succeed as president of the United States.”
----------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project2/webscrapper.py", line 25, in <module>
    text = i.find('p').get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It looks like it doesn't find any `'p'` when iterating div2? Because `i.find('p')` returns `None`, and you get the error after calling `get_text()` on that.

Comment: @Pablo I tried adding an if condition `if text != "": ` after `text = i.find('p').get_text()`, but it still returns the same erro

Comment: @Gabriel _I tried adding an if condition if text != "": after text = i.find('p').get_text()_ That won't change anything, look at the error message, it tells you where things go wrong.

Comment: I would strongly recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Gabriel when you do `text = i.find('p').get_text()`, you are actually doing 2 operations. First getting all the `<p>` tags, and then their text. `i.find('p')` returns `None`. So `None.get_text()` gives you an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment, when you do `text = i.find('p').get_text()`, you are actually doing 2 operations.

First getting all the `<p>` tags, and then their text. `i.find('p')` returns `None` at some point. So `None.get_text()` gives you an error.

You can see this because the error message tells you that `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`.

From the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find):

> If `find_all()` can’t find anything, it returns an empty list. If `find()` can’t find anything, it returns `None`

A quick fix would be to check that `i.find('p')` does not return `None`:

```py
# ...
for elem in section:
    div1 = elem.findAll('div')
    for x in div1:
        div2 = elem.findAll('div')
        for i in div2:
            p = i.find('p')
            if p is not None:
                text = p.get_text()
                print (text)
                print("----------")
```

Also note that `find()` will only return you the first `<p>`, and ignore others if there are.